# using xmpp on iphone ..?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am using xmpp on iphone..but the problem is sometimes when i login  it gives error like this..

```
2010-12-22 12:09:44.074 iPhoneXMPP[2015:20b] SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dXNlcm5hbWU9IihudWxsKSIscmVhbG09InNoYWRvdyIsbm9uY2U9Ing1WTg5dlRGa01ndDRTd3hNY1RWa2lHaHlrN1BxU1pkZGh1Sy9GUmMiLGNub25jZT0iNTFGMzNGNEQtNTBCOC00QzA4LTg2OUUtMUYyNEM5MUM4MkY2IixuYz0wMDAwMDAwMSxxb3A9YXV0aCxkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL2t1bGRlZXAiLHJlc3BvbnNlPTZjODU1MjBmYTUyOTMwMGIxNWUwNGI0OTM0YjhmYzliLGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTg=</response>
2010-12-22 12:09:44.363 iPhoneXMPP[2015:20b] RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
2010-12-22 12:09:44.364 iPhoneXMPP[2015:20b] ---------- xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate: ----------
```

where is the problem...? i can login to account with the spark client...

Comment: Which XMPP library are you using on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

The Base64-decoded version of your SASL response is:

```
username="(null)",
realm="shadow",
nonce="x5Y89vTFkMgt4SwxMcTVkiGhyk7PqSZddhuK/FRc",
cnonce="51F33F4D-50B8-4C08-869E-1F24C91C82F6",
nc=00000001,
qop=auth,
digest-uri="xmpp/kuldeep",
response=6c85520fa529300b15e04b4934b8fc9b,
charset=utf-8
```

From which we can tell you're trying to do [DIGEST-MD5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2831).  Chances are your username isn't (null), so either you have an error in your XMPP library, or in how you are calling it.